# How can I send a Kindle book to the Amazon cloud reader?

Tags: amazon, cloud, kindle

How can I send a book to my Amazon Cloud reader from the Amazon page?

I remember being able to do that before, but know, I can only do 'Deliver to:' my Android device, my PC or my Mac, but the cloud reader is not there. I can't even do this with free books.

I can access the cloud reader at http://read.amazon.com, but I can't add any more books to it.

Comment: Judging by the answers, there must be a legal reason for this restriction?

Answer (score 1):

Kindle versions of purchased books appear in the [Kindle Cloud Reader](https://read.amazon.com/) Library.

Alternatively, when you click on the Buy now with 1-Click button, it takes you to page that has a button "Read now in Kindle Cloud Reader" to let you read your Kindle ebook through your web browser.

Answer (score 1):

First, go [here](http://amazon.com/myk) (http://amazon.com/myk).

Then, sign in and find the tab that says: Manage your devices.

If and only if you can not see a 'device' showing the Kindle cloud reader logo, then contact Amazon.com support. If you can see it, take note of the name. This commonly happens to me, where I forget what it is named.

If you see it there, take note of the name, and still have it not available as an option, make sure you're in the "Manage your devices" tab and click "Deregister." **This will not get rid of any of your content**, however you may need to re-download it again through Kindle cloud reader.